# How can i add movable objects inside a jpg pic?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new in java.
I am trying to build a three bead game.
I am having problems to place 6 movable objects inside a jpg file.
I have tried using JPanel but the objects doesn't show.

Comment: I want to move the objects vertically, horizontally and diagonally.

Comment: Do you know the difference between jpg and jpanel?

Comment: Your first problem is then to show your objects. You need to ask the question by inserting some code of what you have already tried. Tips : `JPanel` is from Swing library, and you put the JavaFX tag, the problem may come from here.

Comment: The jpeg format does not allow you to store layers or store data about parts of the picture (other than pixels). You could of course combine multiple images in JavaFX to produce these visuals, but something like this cannot be stored in a single jpg file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but I suppose you want to display background (a JPG image) and then programatically move three beads on it. If that's the case, there's [Simple tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_images.htm) on how to work with images in JavaFX. To just display image, you need to do the following:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //Creating an image 
    Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("file path"));

    //Setting the image view 1 
    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image); 

    //Creating a Group object  
    Group root = new Group(imageView1);  

    //Creating a scene object 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);  

    //Adding scene to the stage 
    stage.setScene(scene);  

    //Displaying the contents of the stage
    stage.show(); 
}
```

To move beads, you need to keep their state in your application and re-draw it periodically. The tutorial I've mentioned describes basics of pixel manipulation so you may want to check that too.